# Characteristic function of $Z=X-Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ follows Po($\lambda$) and prove that $E[Z^2]=2\lambda$

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution, characteristic-functions

$\lambda$ is a positive real number. Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent each other and follows Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$.

We define $Z = X-Y$.

I need to get a characteristic function of $Z$, $\varphi=E[e^{itZ}]$ and prove that $E[Z^2]=2\lambda$.

---

What I have tried

I have found that Poisson distribution has reproductive property so a parameter of $Z$, $\lambda'$ is $\lambda-\lambda=0$.

Then I got a characteristic function of $$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{e^{itz_i}}{z_i!}=e^{it}$$

But this will not give any functions with $\lambda$ when I want to have a moment of $Z$.

Where did I get wrong?

Comment: Why do you need the characteristic function to solve this? There are simpler ways. It is lucky that the Poisson has the reproductive property, otherwise it might be extinct by now.

Comment: @wolofies I need it because characteristic function is (1) of the problem and $E[Z^2]$ is (2).

Comment: Of course, you do not *need* the characteristic function to *evaluate this expectation*.$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Z^2)&=\mathsf E(X^2-2XY+Y^2)\\&~~\vdots\\&=2\mathsf{Var}(X)\\&=2\lambda\end{align}$$ But, yeah, you are sometimes requested to do things the hard way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $X-Y$ has Poisson distribution  with parameter $\lambda -\lambda$. Obviously $X-Y$ takes negative integer values also, so it cannot have a Poisson distribution.

$Ee^{itX}=\sum e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^{n} e^{itn}} {n!}=e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda e^{it}}=e^{-\lambda (1-e^{it})}$.

Hence $$Ee^{it(X-Y)}=|Ee^{itX}|^{2}=e^{-2\lambda (1-cos ( t))}$$.

To find $EZ^{2}$ differentiate this twice, put $t=0$ and multiply by $-1$.

Comment: Can we always assure that $-E[e^{-itX}]=E[e^{-itX}]$ for $E[e^{it(X-Y)}]=|E[e^{itX}]|^{2}$?

Comment: @ohisamadaigaku Whenever $X,Y$ are i.i.d we have $Ee^{it(X-Y)}=Ee^{itX} Ee^{-itY}=Ee^{itX} Ee^{-itX}$ and $Ee^{-itX}$ is the complex conjugate of $Ee^{itX}$. Hence $Ee^{it(X-Y)}=|Ee^{itX}|^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this part. Then another question is how you got $|Ee^{itX}|^{2}=e^{-2\lambda (1-cos (\lambda t))}$, emersion of $cos(\lambda t)$

Comment: @ohisamadaigaku If $c$ is any complex number then $|e^{c}|=e^{\Re c}$ (by $\Re c$ by I mean the real part of $c$). Note that real part of $-\lambda (1-e^{it})$ is $-\lambda (1-cos t)$.

Comment: ok, so  should the final answer be $e^{-2\lambda(1-cost)}$?

Comment: @ohisamadaigaku Right. I made a mistake at  the end. I have correctd it.